# Are there countries where a member of the legislative branch can have more than one vote?

Tags: legislative-process

In the legislative systems I know individual politicians always have a single vote, although in some cases they may influence other members votes behind the scenes. In the Netherlands it is possible for a single politician to control an entire party (Geet Wilders) but this still doesn't confer extra votes to that person.

Are there any systems in which a single person can cast more than one vote? Say, it is possible to get elected from two districts at the same time or perhaps certain districts have a bigger vote share for their representatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the German *Bundesrat*, provinces have 3 to 6 votes that must be casted as a single bloc. In practice, provinces nominate as many delegates as they have votes and they often vote by a show of hands.

But if there is a roll call, one of them (the *Stimmführer*) will cast all the votes for his or her province. Furthermore, the presence of all the delegates is not required. When others are absent, a single delegate can still cast all the votes of the province and *de facto* has several votes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any where some voters can cast more than one ballot in their own name. But there are [historical examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_voting#Historical_examples) that used weighted voting at points in time - that is, countries where some voters' votes were more equal than others'.

Historical examples include:

- Ancient Rome (where the weight was tied to wealth)
- Sweden until the end of WW1 (where some companies could vote, thus giving their owners more votes)

And to a lesser degree, since these are about segregating by class or race first and foremost:

- A few French colonies (where locals had the same number of representatives as the French)
- Southern Rhodesia (*de jure* segregated voting)

The only current example I'm aware of is the [City of London](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqs5ohhass_QScZFYoQX-7376-Zp654mH), which is a historical peculiarity within London where companies can *still* vote - thus giving their owners (and non-residents) more power than locals.